# Using <jsp:include in div tag

Tags: jsp

I'm developing a web application that creates three divs via a JSP.  The menu div calls a JavaScript function with AJAX that generates a JSP include like

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="screenName.jsp" />
```

Each menu item has a separate JSP for the screen.

AJAX loads the JSP include as TEXT/HTML Content Type into the detail div tag.  I see the JSP include declaration in the div in the browser instead of the content of the JSP include file.

How do I get the browser to execute the content of my JSP include dynamically when a new screen is requested from the menu and not just display the JSP include syntax?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Brandon

Comment: Please post your Javascript function. It sounds like you are just adding in the jsp include on the client-side. JSP is a server-side technology, the user's browser won't execute an include for you...

Comment: Thanks for your post.  My JavaScript is: `code`function getMenuItemScreen( menuString )
         {
            var queryString

            // Get Menu Item Screen
            queryString = "contentType=TEXT/HTML" +
                          "&className=ETSUserEnvironment" +
                          "&methodName=getMenuItemScreen" +
                          "&menuString=/jsp/screens/ets/etsUserSetup.jsp"

            processSynchHttpRequest( url, queryString, requestType, responseType, "detailContainer", "" )
         }

Comment: Thanks for your post.  My JavaScript is:

function getMenuItemScreen( menuString )
{
   var queryString

   // Get Menu Item Screen
   queryString = "contentType=TEXT/HTML" +
                 "&className=ETSUserEnvironment" +
                 "&methodName=getMenuItemScreen" +
                 "&menuString=/jsp/screens/ets/etsUserSetup.jsp"

   processSynchHttpRequest( url, queryString, requestType, responseType, "detailContainer", "" )
}

As you can see, this JavaScript function calls AJAX passing the screen name.  Java creates the <jsp include that's passed back to the browser div.

Comment: I created a servlet that forwards my AJAX request to the JSP.  The JSP screen loads in the div, but the JavaScript won't execute on the page.  The browser says the functions are not there even though they display in View Source.  Any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't get run if it's embedded in HTML that's added using innerHTML. This is for security. Is it possible to make sure the Javascript functions are loaded by the initial page already?

Comment: Mr. Kelly, thanks for your reply.  Would you recommend using an iFrame and simply load my JSP screen there?  This is much more straight forward than using a Servlet, forward to a JSP, than AJAX the output back to the div.  I was trying to avoid iFrames in case they would be deprecated in HTML5.  My original iFrame approach loads all the JavaScript functions included with the JSP screen.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend an iFrame if you can avoid it. It might save you time but they can be a pain to layout properly since they have their own layout. You could drop the Servlet and just make your request directly to the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your JSP is executed on the server, your AJAX function should call the jsp directly rather than insert a jsp:include tag. You can make a request to a Servlet that forwards to a JSP. This will ensure the JSP is run which will output HTML which your AJAX handler will be able to insert into the page.

Any Javascript that is embedded won't be run, however so JavaScript functions need to be already on the page (or in external files loaded by the initial page).